# get Tiramisu submodules llvm for Halide failed with .//3rdParty/llvm: No such file or directory error

Tags: llvm, halide

Hi i'm trying to install tiramisu compiler.

and once trying install it's sub-modules ( (ISL, LLVM and Halide) by using this command

```
dina@dina-VBox:~/tiramisu$ ./utils/scripts/install_submodules.sh ./
```

and i get in the end this error

```
Done installing isl
#### Installing LLVM ####
cd .//3rdParty/llvm
.//utils/scripts/functions.sh: line 6: cd: .//3rdParty/llvm: No such file or directory
```

even one i do ls i find it

```
dina@dina-VBox:~/tiramisu/3rdParty$ ls
clang  Halide  isl  llvm
```

and this is llvm content

```
dina@dina-VBox:~/tiramisu/3rdParty/llvm$ ls
bindings  CMakeLists.txt   configure    docs      include  LICENSE.TXT    llvm.spec.in  README.txt           resources  test   unittests
cmake     CODE_OWNERS.TXT  CREDITS.TXT  examples  lib      LLVMBuild.txt  projects      RELEASE_TESTERS.TXT  runtimes   tools  utils
dina@dina-VBox:~/tiramisu/3rdParty/llvm$
```

What should i do to fix this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try to install as follows

```
./utils/scripts/install_submodules.sh $PWD
```

`$PWD`  returns the full path of the current directory unlike `./` which does not return the full path. The next steps in the installation seem to require the full path.

Comment: I suggest visiting [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in order to get a better insight on how to ask a solid question. Additionally, some code, errors, and a slightly better explanation is necessary in order for others to offer you help (they 1st need to understand what the issue). Hang in there. You'll be great at this.

Comment: Yes true.thank you for sharing your pieces of advice.

Comment: did not get what do you mean exactly by saying that  provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker

Answer (score 0):

The solution shown above fix the problem of 3rdParty folder not found.

But even i fixed this problems many others problem appear and the installation always stop in 66% or 99% . :,(

All the dos lead to closed way :(.

So if you may get in same trouble i shared here in related question of the installation of tiramisu some important tips that should be token into consideration to avoid to fix all this troubles at once and live happy :D :D .

[here is the link.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52706896/llvm-linking-cxx-shared-library-lib-liblto-so-undefiened-refernece-to-targ)