# llvm Linking CXX shared library ../../lib/libLTO.so undefiened refernece to target

Tags: llvm, llvm-clang, halide

i tried to install tiramisu compiler

and once trying install it's sub-modules ( (ISL, LLVM and Halide) by using this command

```
dina@dina-VBox:~/tiramisu$ ./utils/scripts/install_submodules.sh ./
```

i get the error

```
Done installing isl
#### Installing LLVM ####
cd .//3rdParty/llvm
.//utils/scripts/functions.sh: line 6: cd: .//3rdParty/llvm: No such file or directory
```

and to fix it i used the command shared on the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52676881/get-tiramisu-submodules-llvm-for-halide-failed-with-3rdparty-llvm-no-such-fi)

```
./utils/scripts/install_submodules.sh $PWD
```

it worked better then the first one i reached 95% of the installation however it stop here with this error

```
Linking CXX shared library ../../lib/libLTO.so undefiened refernece to target
```

Here is the detail of the error

```
   [ 95%] Linking CXX executable ../../bin/opt
    [ 95%] Linking CXX shared library ../../lib/libLTO.so
    ../../lib/libLLVMX86AsmParser.a(X86AsmParser.cpp.o): In function `llvm::RegisterMCAsmParser<(anonymous namespace)::X86AsmParser>::Allocator(llvm::MCSubtargetInfo const&, llvm::MCAsmParser&, llvm::MCInstrInfo const&, llvm::MCTargetOptions const&)':
    X86AsmParser.cpp:(.text._ZN4llvm19RegisterMCAsmParserIN12_GLOBAL__N_112X86AsmParserEE9AllocatorERKNS_15MCSubtargetInfoERNS_11MCAsmParserERKNS_11MCInstrInfoERKNS_15MCTargetOptionsE+0x164): undefined reference to `llvm::CreateX86AsmInstrumentation(llvm::MCTargetOptions const&, llvm::MCContext const&, llvm::MCSubtargetInfo const*&)'
    CMakeFiles/llvm-mc.dir/llvm-mc.cpp.o: In function `main':
    llvm-mc.cpp:(.text.startup.main+0xe4): undefined reference to `LLVMInitializeX86Disassembler'
    ../../lib/libLLVMX86Desc.a(X86MCTargetDesc.cpp.o): In function `LLVMInitializeX86TargetMC':
    X86MCTargetDesc.cpp:(.text.LLVMInitializeX86TargetMC+0xc7): undefined reference to `llvm::createX86_32AsmBackend(llvm::Target const&, llvm::MCRegisterInfo const&, llvm::Triple const&, llvm::StringRef, llvm::MCTargetOptions const&)'

...
...


    ../../lib/libLLVMAArch64CodeGen.a(AArch64TargetObjectFile.cpp.o):(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN4llvm29AArch64_MachoTargetObjectFileE[_ZTVN4llvm29AArch64_MachoTargetObjectFileE]+0xa0): undefined reference to `llvm::TargetLoweringObjectFileMachO::SelectSectionForGlobal(llvm::GlobalObject const*, llvm::SectionKind, llvm::TargetMachine const&) const'
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
    tools/opt/CMakeFiles/opt.dir/build.make:349: recipe for target 'bin/opt' failed
    make[2]: *** [bin/opt] Error 1
    CMakeFiles/Makefile2:44345: recipe for target 'tools/opt/CMakeFiles/opt.dir/all' failed
    make[1]: *** [tools/opt/CMakeFiles/opt.dir/all] Error 2
    Makefile:151: recipe for target 'all' failed
    make: *** [all] Error 2
    dina@dina-VBox:~/tiramisu$ ^C
```

I do not know what should i do to fix this new error can someone help please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not been able to fix the problem on it's self but i have changed the way of installing tiramisu.

I did pay attention to that and i do want to pay your attention to too that may serve your time and success your installation.

- Never ever install tiramisu on virtual box cause tiramisu require a bit high performance machine i mean at least 6G of RAM once compiling it consume >= 6GRAM.

  Means it's better to have partition or Linux system directly.
- You may find issues from version to version means some succeed to install it in 18.04 where some in 16 where some in 14. So if you fail in version never give up try another version better then still paralyzed.
- It better to not lunch anything in parallel once installing tiramisu.
- You need to have a good network to clone tiramisu sub-modules and tiramisu on itself with a network of 35kb/s it may took 24h to get clone all stuff.
- Respect the all the tips listed to install tiramisu to avoid have trouble ex if it's said you should CMake 5.0 version do it because they have tested in this version and they insure that work nothing grantee that in 6 version it will work so be careful.
- If you scattered things in the way that you could not fix issues. It's better to clean up everything and restart from "0".
- Be patient : Installing tiramisu is a bit heavy task so be Broad-minded and Zen.

it took me one month to be able to install tiramisu i had many issues. But once i install it in a partition and doing the steps show above carefully i have been finally to install successfully.

Best of luck :).